# Как закрасить только часть полотна canvas?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

У меня в программе есть виджет canvas, залитый одним цветом, желтым, к примеру. И я хочу, зная координаты точек, образующих на полотне прямоугольник, залить его другим цветом, синим, например. Как это сделать?

Comment: Нарисовать и залить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто нарисовать прямоугольник с нужными координатами и заливкой:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_rectangle(50, 25, 150, 75, fill="yellow", width=0)

root.mainloop()
```